# How do you manage to work with Paypal to create a pledge like system into your app.?

Tags: php, paypal

just a pure naive question into how will I implement a specific feature using Paypal, so the idea is how do I implement it in a web application that I have.

I want to create a feature that's like pledging to a specific cause only this time users can pledge to add more to a specific money that's stored in the database.

So the users can add more to the money in the bet. Think of it as a betting system only that users will have to bet using their own currency and then when they place their bet it will be automatically converted to the original currency of the bet. For example if they bet 25USD then it will be converted to British pOunds and be added to that original value.